# Recover git repository from vscode

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode to make a website with HTML, PHP, CSS, JavaScript, etc. and I just lost a lot of my progress.

When I started with this project I init'ed a github repository. I could sync or push, nothing got uploaded to GitHub. But as I was short of time, I continued to program.

As I was playing around with vscode I opened a new branch to see what happened, continued programming on that branch. Today I turned to master again. Just realized that I have lost all my progress.

**Is there a way to recover it?** It seems that the files are not on my pc, and when I looked into GitHub, again, no repository was created.

I don't know if this is a StackOverflow question, but if nobody knows I will erase it soon, I'm really desperate.

Comment: Did you make commits while working?

Comment: Yes, but nothing got commited on github...:( or at least i can't see the repository in my profile. I'm not frequent user of github honestly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the folder of your project. Open shell or cmd in that foldeer. Use the command below ro get your files back.

```
git checkout <old_branch_name>
```

Or you can simply merge the old branch to master if you have committed it.

```
git checkout master
git merge <old_branch_name>
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't know if this would have worked, but i think is the same thing a just did. I recovered everything. I think that after i saw everything was missed i was so nervous that i wasn't thinking right. Just came back to life.

Comment: @Hernan: the moral of the story is to push your work to a remote regularly, it is like a zero-effort backup.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your code is just on another branch.

`git checkout [branch]`

---

If your code is on the same branch, but you accidentally deleted the files use:

`git reset --hard`

This will revert to the state of the previous commit, essentially un-deleting your files.

Comment: What happens? What about running `git log` and then `git checkout [commit]`?

Comment: @Hernan: judging by your other remarks, this _did_ work?

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
git reflog
```

This will output something like this:

```
f91a6fd HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from 3 to 4
8588104 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from master to 3
1a17da4 HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from 2 to master
01c34aa HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from 1 to 2
1a17da4 HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from d7142f4fc79fe6618381e00802a27e5d79d3566c to master
bb17da4 HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from login to d7142f4fc79fe6618381e00802a27e5d79d3566c
```

This is ordered from newest to oldest changes. Let's say you need to change back to "d7142f4fc79fe6618381e00802a27e5d79d3566c". You then run:

```
git checkout d7142f4fc79fe6618381e00802a27e5d79d3566c
```